# wpf Assembly resources which contains different namespacces

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, resources

I'm not familiar with resources.

I have the following lines of code:

`Dim pixelShader As PixelShader = New PixelShader()
            pixelShader.UriSource = New Uri("/Shazzam.Shaders;component/Effects/PivotEffect.ps", UriKind.Relative)`

I need to know what is wrong in my "Uri" line of code.

The file PivotEffect.ps  is located in the folder "Effects" and has a "Build Action" property set to "Resource".

The file PivotEffect.vb looks like the following:

```
Namespace Shazzam.Shaders
    Public Class PivotEffect
    Inherits ShaderEffect........
End Class   End Namespace
```

This file has a namespace named "Shazzam.Shaders". Does it make difference in resouse uri?

the XAML code is:

```html
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppName"
<local:MyControl.Effect>                            
    <Shaders:PivotEffect PivotAmount="5" Edge="8"/>
</local:MyControl.Effect>
```

and the error message in XAML browser is "Can't load file or assembly 'Shazzam.Shaders, Culture= neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system can't find the file specified"

What is the problem in my "Uri"?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the uri line to be as follow:

```
pixelShader.UriSource = New Uri("/AppName;component/Effects/PivotEffect.ps", UriKind.Relative)
```